# How validate 2 fields in alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

Say there are two linked fields in a form and the values of the first one depend on the second. How do I write a custom constraint for them?

Comment: Do you want to validate it in share, on on save?

Comment: Yes on save. I am considering to use FormFilter now, but have not found how to mark field as error before persiste :(